Division rings Jacobson’s commutativity theorem
I have a question, if you can help me, related to this theorem: I don't quite understand what I need to demonstrate and what is meant by $n(a, b)$. Let D be a division ring such that , for any $a,b \in D$, there exists an integer $n = n(a ,b) > 1$ such that $(ab - ba)^n = ab - ba$. Then D is a field.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial. Here $n(a,b)$ means that this $n>1$ will depend on $a$ and $b$.

The notation   $n(a ,b)$ is being used simply to emphasize that the integer $n$ depends on the values of $a$ and $b$. It is not necessarily true that the same integer $n$ will work for all possible choices of $a$ and $b$.

@MichaelCohen Please put your solution in the solution section. thanks.

@rscwieb Now done

The notation $n(a,b)$ is being used simply to emphasize that the integer $n$ depends on the values of $a$ and $b$. It is not necessarily true that the same integer $n$ will work for all possible choices of $a$ and $b$.
